# Jquery datepicker and Spring MVC internationalization

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, locale, jquery-ui-datepicker

Good day folks. Please help me. I have Jquery datepicker:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["ru"]);

                     $("#dateinput").datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                            beforeShowDay: beforeShowDayHandler,
                            showOn: 'both',
                            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
                            },
                            beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                            }

                        });


function beforeShowDayHandler(date) {
                            if (self.SelectedDayValue != -1) {
                                if (date.getDate() != 1) {
                                    return [false, '', 'selected'];
                                }
                            }
                            return [true, ''];
                        }

                         jQuery(function ($) {
```

Presently I have locale on russian. How can I take locale parameter for my date picker on jsp age.

My jsp page:

```
   <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title><spring:message code="label.input.head" var="headTitle"/></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/select2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/cssFiles/select2.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/select2_e.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/cssFiles/inputStyle.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/cssFiles/jquery-ui.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {  

                     $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['<%response.getLocale().getLanguage(); %>']);

                     $("#dateinput").datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                            beforeShowDay: beforeShowDayHandler,
                            showOn: 'both',
                            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
                            },
                            beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                            }

                        });

                        function beforeShowDayHandler(date) {
                            if (self.SelectedDayValue != -1) {
                                if (date.getDate() != 1) {
                                    return [false, '', 'selected'];
                                }
                            }
                            return [true, ''];
                        }

                         jQuery(function ($) {
                                console.log($('.widthclass').select2_e().on('change', function () { }));
                            });              
                    }); 
             </script>

</head>


<body>

//other omitted....

</body>
```

Spring servlet config locale:

```
<!-- Change my local over url variable lang. Example: ?lang=en -->
<interceptors>
    <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
         <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </beans:bean>
</interceptors>
```

I hope this going to be enough information.  I want when user change locale it will change datepicker locale automatically too. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use request interceptor to populate model with locale:

```
public class PagePopulationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        if(modelAndView != null) {
            Locale locale = response.getLocale();
                        modelAndView.addObject("currentLocale", locale.getLanguage());
        }
    }

}
```

Also you need some configuration for interceptor:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="your.package.util.PagePopulationInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

After that you can access locale language via ${currentLocale}

OR

Easier, but dirtier way is to use scriptlet:

```
<%= response.getLocale().getLanguage() %>
```

You dont need to register intercepter, but it is not clean to have java code in your jsp.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @The User 518469. I have question if you not mind. Where should I locate my request interceptor in application. And what you think about String locale = response.getLocale().toString(); This also can get locale, right?? And how can I fit language request interceptor to my  jQuery code. Sorry if it too much.

Comment: 1. You create interceptor class (e.g. PageInterceptor) in any package (e.g. com.myapp.util). Then you must specify full class name in configuration: <bean class="com.myapp.util.PageInterceptor" />

Comment: 2. String locale = response.getLocale().toString() is simple, but it is scriptlet (embedding java code to jsp page). It is not restrcited to use scriptlets, but it is not good practice to mix html and code. 
PageInterceptor is useful when you need to put some data from DB to EVERY page (e.g. user profile). If it is not your case - easier is to use scriptlet.

Comment: 3. If you have jquery initialization code of your plugin in separate .js file (not at jsp) you have to do some workaround:  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[CURRENT_LOCALE]); where CURRENT_LOCALE is js variable. Than at the beginning of your jsp add code: <script>var CURRENT_LOCALE = "<%= request.getLocale().getLanguage() %>";</script>. This code must be BEFORE plugin initialization

Comment: Sir, your answers so strong professional.  Sir. About JQuery very interesting. I have JQuery like a regular plugin and some code on jsp page to build datepicker itself. I will add whole jsp page to understand more clearly. Please would you rather tell me if i will have interceptor which will intercept a request when I change the locale and at the same time will change it on datepicker? I can not do this with scriptlet, right??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I add my full JSP file for you to see how I have my JQuery datepicker installed  on JSP page. Just when I change locale the datepicker locale do not change itself with locale.. I'm thinking the problem is because I don't have interceptor  witch responsible to intercept locale in put it into datepicker locale for me before pae loads>> Right??

Comment: There is another way to determine current user locale: use ${cookie.locale.value}. You use LocaleChangeInterceptor - it saves users locale to special cookie "locale". But in that case after changing locale you must refresh your page after setting new locale.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35297/discussion-between-the-user-518469-and-user-jvm)

Comment: Where did you take ${cookie.locale.vale}?? It should be some of the code in controller??